Daytime and Nightime Occurrence Duration of an Event
I want to find the daytime and night-time occurrence duration of an event from its' start time to end time.
The event duration is volatile and can take place for a long time.
I can't figure out a formula.
I am seeking to figure out the duration with a formula or VBA code or Python code.
Link to the sample file with manually calculated duration for each event. The event occurs in multiple scenarios to be considered.


I think the explanation in "DayNight" tab of your own sheet is exactly what you need. The logic is well explained in that sheet too.

So you may want to look at calculating across midnight - if this helps give it a vote : https://stackoverflow.com/a/78663289/4961700

Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel have different feature sets and may require a different answer each. The [google-sheets] tag description explicitly states "Do NOT use with [excel]" and the [excel] tag description explicitly states "Do NOT use with other spreadsheet software like [google-sheets]." Choose one platform and edit tags appropriately.

If you find it hard to calculate NightTime, I suggest you calculate DayTime first, and use TotalHourse - DayTime for night time, then you wouldn't need to worry about "crossing midnight".
So, for day time duration, here is the formula (in K10)
=(INT(E10)-INT(D10))*(F10-G10)-MEDIAN(MOD(D10,1),G10,F10)+MEDIAN(MOD(E10,1),G10,F10)
For night time duration:
=E10-D10-K10 (in L10)

Finally, remember to format your cell as [h]:mm:ss:

Explaining the formula:

think of INT(E10)-INT(D10) as number of days between start date and end date. (including start date, but excluding end date).

INT(E10)-INT(D10) * (18 -6) can be interpreted as number of dayTime hours from start date to end date. (start date inclusive, end date exclusive)

To get number of hours between 12/09/2024 7:00 and 13/09/2024 16:00, we need to deduct extra hours from start date, and add extra hours to the end date. i.e we need to deduct (7:00-6:00) from 12/09, and add (16:00 -6:00) for 13/09.
that is, (13/09/2024 - 12/09/2024) * (18 -6) -(7-6) + (16-6) is the number of dayTime hours between 12/09/2024 7:00 to 13/09/2024 16:00.
It can be simplified to (13/09/2024 - 12/09/2024) * (18 -6)  + 16 -7

If start time on start date is outside DayTime Hours,
e.g for 12/09/2024 4:00 to 13/09/2024 16:00, we just treat it as ifstart date starts at 6:00. i.e (13/09/2024 - 12/09/2024) * (18 -6) - (6-6) + (16 - 6) = (13/09/2024 - 12/09/2024) * (18 -6) + 16 -6

If end time on end date is outside DayTime hours, e. for  12/09/2024 4:00 to 13/09/2024 19:00, we just treat it as if end date ends at 18:00. i.e (13/09/2024 - 12/09/2024) * (18 -6) - (6-6) + (18 - 6) = (13/09/2024 - 12/09/2024) * (18 -6) + 18 -6

Finally, 4 & 5 can be simplified with -MEDIAN(start hour,6,18)+MEDIAN(end hour, 6, 18)



Thanks a lot for the help. This really worked out for me. I had been trying to figure out this one for months but can't. Can you please help me to explain the formula for daytime about how did you approached to this problem. Thanks a lot again.

@BruyneZeus, I added an explanation of the formula, hopefully it is straightforward enough.

you can treat this problem in the same way as finding the intersection interval between two lines(one of the lines being your daytime duration)[subtracting from total time duration gives you night time], you can check for the code online to have some insights. What is important here is implementing logic for when the start and end day are not the same, then you'd have to calculate separately for the end and start day and add a (constant daytime time*number of days between those 2 days).
This is my first response to any query, apologies if my help was not of use.
Best of luck for your task!

Thanks for your suggestions and now my problem was solved by Rachel

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Verbose, spill formula (Microsoft 365), not as compact and elegant as rachel's:
(Almost) following the logic in the "DayNight" sheet:
=LET(
    last_data_cell, XLOOKUP(TRUE, G10:G500 <> "", G10:G500, , , -1),
    shift_data, D10:last_data_cell,
    shift_hours, LAMBDA(acc, shift_row,
        LET(
            start, INDEX(shift_data, shift_row, 1),
            end, INDEX(shift_data, shift_row, 2),
            night_start_hour, INDEX(shift_data, shift_row, 3),
            day_start_hour, INDEX(shift_data, shift_row, 4),
            total_hours, (end - start) * 24,

            day_hours, IFS(
                end <= (INT(start) + day_start_hour),
                0,
                DAYS(end, start) = 0,
                IF(
                    start > (INT(start) + night_start_hour),
                    0,
                    MIN(end, INT(end) + night_start_hour) -
                        MAX(start, INT(start) + day_start_hour)
                ),
                DAYS(end, start) > 0,
                (
                    DAYS(end, start) *
                        (night_start_hour - day_start_hour)
                ) -
                    IF(
                        start > (INT(start) + day_start_hour),
                        start - INT(start) - day_start_hour,
                        0
                    ) +
                    IF(
                        end > INT(end) + day_start_hour,
                        MIN(end, INT(end) + night_start_hour) -
                            INT(end) - day_start_hour,
                        0
                    )
            ) * 24,

            VSTACK(
                acc,
                HSTACK(day_hours, total_hours - day_hours, total_hours)
            )
        )
    ),
    REDUCE(
        {
            "Day Time Duration (Hours)",
            "Night Time Duration (Hours)",
            "Total Duration"
        },
        SEQUENCE(ROWS(shift_data)),
        shift_hours
    )
)



Thank you for your inputs, this also worked for me. Thanks

Glad to hear it! And thank you for providing well detailed and easy to use sample files.
